# Wistia videos not appearing on Phonegap app on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, wistia

I have a Phonegap app for iOS that allows for Wisita videos to be embedded in an iFrame.

When I try to view these videos on a mobile iOS device, these videos never appear (as if nothing was contained in the iFrame).

The embed code I am using is as follows:

```
<iframe>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/foobar.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_foobar" style="height:349px">&nbsp;</div>
</iframe>
```

**EDIT** - I have also now tried the following embed code:

```
<iframe class="wistia_embed" frameborder="0" id="iframe-content" name="wistia_embed" scrolling="no" src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/foobar?videoFoam=true">
</iframe>
<script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/iframe-api-v1.js"></script>
```

Note that both of these methods of embedding work fine on Google Chrome on desktop.

I found the following on Wistia's Status page for the inline playback for mobile rollout under "known issues":

> - iframe embeds will continue to use the native mobile player. These two don't currently play nicely together in iOS (the fullscreen
>     control won't work with iframe embeds).

Does anyone know how to get Wistia embeds working on an iOS device in an iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a protocol to those urls, in Cordova apps if you don't provide one, then file: will be used.

So, add `http:` or `https:` before the `//` on every src of your example.

Also, you will have to allow the navigation to those urls inside the app, so you have to add the `allow-navigation` tag to your `config.xml` like this:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://fast.wistia.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://fast.wistia.net/*" />
```

or this ones if you added https

```
<allow-navigation href="https://fast.wistia.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://fast.wistia.net/*" />
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks a lot.